# Python pandas read_csv() utf-8 csv file containing both EOF and NULL byte

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, null, eof

I have a utf-8 encoded file containing both EOF and NULL byte.

Understood the solution to read EOF into dataframe is using engine='python' and to read NULL byte is using engine='c', how should I resolve this?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

### Executed the following codes:

```
pd.read_csv('extract.csv', sep = ",", encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', engine='python')
```

### Received this error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be
>   processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass
>   in engine='c' instead

### Amended to the following:

```
pd.read_csv('extract.csv', sep = ",", encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', engine='c')
```

### Received this error:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside
>   string starting at line 0

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: There is no EOF byte. "EOF inside string" means the file ended in the middle of something.

Comment: I think attaching a minimal set of data to replicate this issue would be very helpful in diagnosing it.

Comment: A csv file should be a text file. Having NULL bytes in it is weird and a hint that it is not a correct csv file and it should either be cleaned or processed with a different tool. Could you share some rows exhibiting the problem? BTW NULL are often an indice of UTF16 encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not being written correctly, and starts with a `nul` `\0` char

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> with open("extract.csv", 'wb') as fh:
...   fh.write(b"\0")
...
1
>>> pd.read_csv('extract.csv', sep = ",", encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', engine='python')
Traceback (most recent call last):
[omitted]
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[omitted]
pandas.errors.ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead
```

If your file is appears to be empty/extremely small, it's probably being written improperly and is just missing its contents.

If your file does have contents, you may be able to resolve the problem by starting a little deeper into it (`fh.seek()` method)

```py
with open("extract.csv", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    fh.seek(1)  # step forward into the file before attempting to read it
    pd.read_csv(fh, sep = ",", encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', engine='python')
```

Files have a pointer which indicates where you're reading them at. By starting a little further into it, you can skip over the `nul` byte before passing it to pandas (which should work with [any file-like object with a `.read()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table))

If your file is empty, you'll get a different error

```py
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```